# Using TaskFactory.FromAsync to call a SOAP Web service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a web service with different asynchronous methods and their completed_eventhandlers. Whenever the webservice method completes it executes its event handler. Now, in my service layer I have a generic method that will call these async webservice methods using Func delegate. Please note all the webservice methods have same type of signature.

Please guide me how to use Task, so that my service layer method is also async, in order to call these async methods and provide the response received from the event handler to the user.

Framework is .NET 4.0

Please guide with an example

Comment: Use the Begin.. methods, those are asnych allready. A quick google will yield lots of examples.

Comment: This should be a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx.  You could clarify your question by showing a bit of code, how does your service layer look like? How would you like to call it?

Comment: If you want, you can use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` along with the `Begin...` methods.

Comment: The service layer is a simple generic class with a method. It will be called like var ex = new Example<inputParameter,outParameter,delegateMethod(); ex.ServiceCall(); Please note I want to use Task with a Event-based asynchronous pattern (EAP). I found a link http://www.damirscorner.com/WrappingOtherAsynchronousPatternsInAwaitableTasks.aspx and giving it a try

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 4.5 you can just create a proxy that returns tasks for asynchronous calls instead of APM-style methods (BeginX/EndX)

In .NET 4 you can convert the APM methods to a Task using Task.Factory.FromAsync. Assuming your service method receives a single parameter:

```
public MyResponse MyCall(MyRequest request);
```

You can use code like this to convert the APM-style call (Begin/End) to a Task:

```
var myRequestObject =...;

var callTask=Task<MyResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        client.BeginMyCall, 
        client.EndMyCall, 
        myRequestObject,
        null);  // The state object, typically not used
```

To work with more arguments, use one of the overloads that accept more arguments (up to 3)

The multiple FromAsync overloads can be very confusing and the compiler can complain a lot that it can't find the types of the generic parameters.

The trick is to understand that the first argument just needs the IAsyncResult object while the second argument requires the function that will handle the end results. Even the overloads that accept a Func<> as a first parameter, run it immediatelly and keep working with the IAsyncResult

The above call is equivalent to this:

```
var ar=client.BeginMyCall(myRequestObject,null,null);
var callTask=Task<MyResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(ar,client.EndMyCall);
```

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis. But FromAsync can be used only for Asynchronous Programming Model (APM) not for Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP), correct?

Comment: You *did* ask about a web service which means you have to use the APM style. If you want to convert an EAP style call, you need to use a TaskCompletionSource. Check the link provided by @Rudi. There's even an EAP example there at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622454.aspx